# Reversing sorted dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm sorting my dictionary by key, but I'd like to reverse the order. However I'm not getting much joy with a few of the examples I have seen around the web.

Here is the sort

```
tempdict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(tempdict.items()))
```

now I'm trying:

```
reverse = collections.OrderedDict(tempdict.items()[::-1])
reverse = collections.OrderedDict(map(reversed, tempdict.items()))
```

But these are not working. What is the smartest and most elegant way of sorting the dictionary. Yes I know, dictionaries are not really used for the sorting, but this works well for us. Thanks.

Comment: Please show with an example

Comment: `reverse = collections.OrderedDict(list(tempdict.items())[::-1])` will work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To sort in reverse order:

```
collections.OrderedDict(sorted(tempdict.items(), reverse=True))
```

To reverse an existing dict:

```
collections.OrderedDict(reversed(list(tempdict.items())))
```

Comment: Well, um, surely it's not *entirely* different, since it gives the correct result. But yea, I missed the title and misunderstood the post because of that.

Comment: Apparently there are two ways to read the question — let's wait for the OP.

Comment: It's been 84 years... and we are still waiting for the OP

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> d = collections.OrderedDict([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])
>>> collections.OrderedDict(reversed(list(d.items())))
OrderedDict([(5, 6), (3, 4), (1, 2)])
```